# javascript getting input checkbox on table using col and row

Tags: javascript

I want to make proses where my data is exist the checkbox will become `false`, so here is the image that i tried, and using with console.
[image]

I tried to get the column and row to make checkbox become false like here.

```
    let tblModul = document.getElementById('myTable');
    console.log('col :' + col);
    console.log('row :' + row);
    const [intersections, difference, falsecheked] = datarelationships(theemployee, theEmpDatInTable, 'nik', 'NIK');
    appendTheTableEmployee(difference.length, tbody, difference)
    console.log(falsecheked);
    if(falsecheked == false){
        tblModul.rows[row].cells[col].checked = false;
    }
```

Is there a problem with my code? because eventough i got the value false, the checkbox didn't unchecked

Comment: Can you create fiddle or something so at least others can reproduce issue and solve it.

Comment: Also from image it seems that your `col` value should be `2` or higher. Because your first two columns doesn't seems to have `checkbox`.

Comment: @Karan thank you i realized something so crucial because of your comment :D i make my checkbox -1 for col and + 1 for row before this in another functions, and didn't realize that,  thank youu so much,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `tblModul.rows[row].cells[col].checked = false;` which will try to set `checked = false` on `cell` but you need to perform it on `input` inside that `cell`. So you can use like `tblModul.rows[row].cells[col].querySelector('input').checked = false;`.

Try it below.

```js
let tblModul = document.getElementById('myTable');
// in your code use row & col variables I have statically used for testing.
tblModul.rows[0].cells[0].querySelector('input').checked = false;
tblModul.rows[1].cells[0].querySelector('input').checked = true;
```

```html
<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' checked></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' checked></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```